# Keep conditional formatting color but remove conditions-on one spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have been looking over this conditional formatting issue over this weekend but unable to find any solution to it.

Both my tables are on one single tab of a spreadsheet.

ALL data tables are created using `Index` and `Match`.

I need the third table to have values of table 2 but ONLY color formatting of table 1.

I am attaching an image herewith.

[image: Conditional formatting data]

Comment: You should be able to give the cells in table 3 the same conditions as the corresponding cells in table 1.

Comment: ^^ Think what @cybernetic.nomad is saying is have the conditional formatting rules for those cells with the same conditions pointing at the first table cells for the values to test.

Comment: There's always this article: https://excel.tips.net/T001947_Removing_Conditional_Formats_but_Not_the_Effects.html

Comment: Hi cybernetic.nomad, the cells in Table 2 do not have an conditions. Table 2 is related to Table 1. Table 1 is say $ but table 2 is say quantities. It is just an example. I just want to show that when in red in Table 1, it also shows in Table 2/3. Hope this helps...I know this is confusing.

Comment: I will soon tryout the suggestion given in the blog...thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give you an example:

Let us assume the condition for formatting A1 as red is that A1 contains a value greater 2. So the condition for A1 would be `=A1>2`.

To format B1 also red when A1 is red, we just need to use the same condition on that cell. So condition for B1 is `=A1>2` and it gets formatted red as soon as A1 contains a value greater 2.

*Note that the formatting of B1 only depends on the value of A1 but is completely independent from the value of B1.*

Now you can transfer that to your issue and your conditions.

See the screenshot for the condition (sorry for the german screenshot):
[image]

Comment: Hi PEH, thanks for the reply. I have done the following in my table: In Table 1, I have first carried out an Index and Match and then applied conditional formatting. Table 2 also is an index and Match....and I need color from Table 1 applied to Table 2 so as to get Table 3.

Comment: @excelislife I already understood what you want and my answer explains exactly how to do that (on an example). You just need to transfer that to your issue (give your table2 a conditional formatting with the same conditions of table1). We cannot do it for you but just point you into the right direction.

Comment: Danke schoen Herr PEH...I genuinely tried out your awesome solution but it is highlighting random cells and not the ones which should be the mirror image...I have about 7000 cells in my conditional formatted spreadsheet...

Comment: @excelislife as we don't know anything about your sheet and especially how you set your conditions, this is the only hint I can give you. That would definitely work if you did it right.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!